# Converting NFA to DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I've converted an NFA to a DFA.  But even after checking over it a few times, it still doesn't feel right.  I'm sure this is trivial, but I'd like someone to give me an idea where I went totally wrong on this.

NFA:

[image: NFA]

DFA:

[image: DFA]

Comment: Why would you say it doesn't feel right? It does to me.

Comment: You could use ony drawing tool to get nicer images (Libre Office Draw, GraphViz, LaTeX with TikZ, ...). *At least* you can crop and rotate the images properly, convert to grayscale and fiddle around with contrast and brightness. As for your question, there are algorithms to do this conversion; why do you doubt them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, of course you have to merge the two empty states and there should be two transitions $(\{q_5\}, a, \emptyset)$ and $(\{q_5\}, b, \emptyset)$ if you want a complete automaton, but otherwise, it looks right and I agree with Subhayan: both automata accept $ab^+ \cup ab^+a$.

Comment: I added $(\{q_5\}, a, \emptyset)$ and $(\{q_5\}, b, \emptyset)$ so it just merges with the $\emptyset$ closest to it. So there's still two $\emptyset$ on the graph.  How wrong is that?  It's really for convenience when drawing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong as long as you know that these two empty states can be merged. What I mean is that you obtained an automaton with 5 states, not with 6 states. One can prove actually that it is the minimal automaton of your language. This would be the next exercise...

Answer (score 2):

Based on your constructions, it seems like both machines accept the same language, i.e. $ab^+ \cup ab^+a$.

Comment: Could you give an idea of how you reached that conclusion?

Comment: i tried to "simulate the machines" independently, it _seemed to me_ that the DFA and NFA both accepted languages that start with $a$, contains at-least one $b$ and also those (with the same conditions as prev and) that end with an $a$.
Do you think I got it wrong somehow?

Comment: no, not at all, just trying to encourage the best answer possible :)

Comment: *phew* :) ... although i should have made that explicit in the answer itself.. anyway, thanks to you we got that covered now.